Entity Framework Core v7+ : execute delete on foreign key related tables without navigation property
I have a following two tables each with millions of record so performance for delete is needed
Table Product
(
    DateOf date not null, 
    Type varchar(100) not null,
    ProductId int not null,
    ProductCategory varchar(100) not null
    Primary Key (DateOf,Type)
)

Table ProductListing
(
    DateOf date not null, 
    Type varchar(100) not null,
    RowId int identity(1,1) not null,
    Quantity int not null,
    Primary key(DateOf,Type,RowId)
    Foreign key (DateOf,Type) references Product (DateOf,Type)
)

usually the deletion of record occurs by DateOf and ProductCategory (note this field is not part of primary key)
I have code EF code like assuming user passes date and category parameters
dbContext.Product.Where(p=> p.DateOf = date && p.ProductCategory = category).ExecuteDelete()

This correctly deletes the corresponding records from Product table but we need to delete the record from ProductListing table too efficiently. Ideal delete statement would be
Delete pl from 
ProductListing pl
inner join Product p on p.DateOf=pl.DateOf and p.Type=pl.Type -- join on foreign key
where
-- below are the parameters passed by user
p.DateOf = date
and p.ProductCategory = category

so I want to generate above delete statement using entity framework and execute it before deleting from Product table and execute the product delete as shown above in a transaction.
I am not sure how can I force entity framework core to produce such delete statement. Please note that the above delete statement is need as number of records are huge and this single statement takes care of deletion in one statement
Please note cascade delete on table can't be added due to legacy data reasons.

Instead of tables please add classes with their navigation properties.

Without navigation properties you can use the following queries:
using var transaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

// common filter for Products
var productsToDelete = dbContext.Product
    .Where(p => p.DateOf == date && p.ProductCategory == category);

var prdocutListing = 
    from pl in dbContext.ProductListing
    from p in productsToDelete.Where(p => p.DateOf == pl.DateOf && p.Type == pl.Type)
    select pl;

prdocutListing
    .ExecuteDelete();

productsToDelete
    .ExecuteDelete();

transaction.Commit();


Thanks for your answer but as mentioned in question the navigation property is not defined on model class. Can you please suggest alternate solution? Thanks for your time.

Suggested, if you want help in LINQ queries, post classes instead of tables.
